# mail send using c# but data has to fetch from other html page

Tags: c#, html, email, send

Can anybody tell me how to fetch data of html page in c# module.
i want send direct mail to client from html page.
for that i have to fetch data from html to c# module.. and write a code of c# mail send on server.. how is this possible..plz help me

Comment: If my answer solved the case, please mark the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `WebClient` to do that.

The `WebClient`-class contains the function `DownloadString`, that downloads the Uri specified as a string.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string data = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
```